# cannot attach an event handler in HTML created by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I am trying to build a calendar using this [tutorial](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/) which uses backbone and the jquery FullCalendar plugin.
I want to attach a click event handler to a cell(weekday view) of the calendar-this is the code I tried for testing:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $('.fc-event-time').click(function()
{
  alert('test');
});

});
```

The above does not work.fc-event-time is the class associated with the cell that contains the time.Here is an image of the cell with some notes in it.
[image](http://sdrv.ms/1buDDJF)

The whole calendar is created with JS.The only HTML required is a div named calendar.Can that be the reason why the event handler cannot be attached.
Look at some code to see what I am talking about:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/fcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fcalendar/apllication.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fcalendar/custom_cal_code.js"></script>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
```

fullcalendar.js is the file the created the calendar inside div#calendar.Application.js is the backbone code(REST,render functions,models etc) which adds some functionality to the calendar and custom_cal_code.js is my code you see above-which tries to attach the event handler.Jquery dependencies are not shown above for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that at the point when your binding the event those elements don't yet exist in the DOM. Instead try using [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation) by binding to an existing higher level element.

For example you can use jQuery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#calendar').on('click', '.fc-event-time', function () {
 alert('test');
});
```

Comment: it does not work...I do not think your code is wrong.Something else is preventing the code to work which I am trying to find what it is.I will do some jsfiddle testing...well the code in fiddle works(http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/sQfa7/2/)...so something in my scripts prevents the code from running

Comment: it works after all...I implemented in the  monthview of the calendar and it is OK.In the weekview proper class targeting must be done...something I have not achieved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS (for reference) example of a test case for what I think you want. Jack's answer will also work perfectly well for jQuery selectors.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x24ER/2/

code:

```
(function () {
  var cal = document.getElementById('cal');
  var myFn = function (e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'fc-event-time') {
      alert('clicked');
    }
  };
  cal.addEventListener('click', myFn);
})();
```